# dismiss modal view to different uiview

Tags: uiview, modalviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller, addsubview

I have a uiview that has a subview. That subview has a button that loads a modalViewController. Then When I use `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` I need it to go back to the uiview with the subview, not just the subview that presents the modal view.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you can remove a subview with:

```m
[subView removeFromSuperview];
```

You can just call that right before your `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated` or use the `completion:(Block)` parameter if you want it to only go away after the brief animation:

```m
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
  [subView removeFromSuperview];
}];
```